# Locally connectivity in terms of connected sets of small diameter

Tags: general-topology

> Suppose that $(X,d)$ is a compact metric space. Prove that $X$ is locally connected if and only if for each $\epsilon>0$, there is a finite cover of $X$ by compact connected sets of diameter less than $\epsilon$.

My attempt for $(\Rightarrow)$:

Let $\epsilon>0$. Since $X$ is a compact metric space, it is totally bounded.  Therefore there exists $x_1,...x_n\in X$ such that 
$$X=\bigcup_{i=1}^n B_d(x_i,\epsilon).$$ 
For each $x_i$, $B_d(x_i,\epsilon)$ is a neighborhood of $x_i$.  Since $X$ is locally connected there exists $k_i$ such that $x_i \in B_d(x_i,k_i) \subset B_d(x_i,\epsilon)$.

I don't know how to proceed.  If I take the closure of $B_d(x_i,k_i)$, then $B_d(x_i,k_i)$ is compact since it is a closed subset of a compact space.  And the closure of a connected set is still connected.  So I would have a compact connected set but their union doesn't necessarily seem to cover $X$ does it?

Answer (score 3):

Every $x$ in $X$ has arbitarily small connected open neighbourhoods (this is the definition of locally connected), so if $\varepsilon > 0$ is given, find for every $x$ some open neighbourhood $O_x$ of $x$ such that $O_x$ is connected and $\operatorname{diam}(O_x) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$. (E.g. this can be done by finding a connected open neighbourhood of $x$ inside $B(x,\frac{\varepsilon}{4})$, e.g.). Then find a finite subcover of the $O_x$ and take the closures of those $O_x$ (which are also connected and have diameter $\le \frac{\varepsilon}{2} < \varepsilon$). Done.